# Buscando valor array dentro de outro array e retornar

Tags: javascript

Observem o cenário:

Eu tenho o seguintes array's

`let arr = [23,0,0]`

```
let coresLinhasPorPocsag = ["#4d79ff", "#ff6600", "#00cc88", "#b31aff"]
```

Preciso pegar a cor de acordo com posição do array `arr`

Eu consigo pegar da primeira cor, porém quando passa novamente no ele retorna com `undefined` alguém pode me ajudar a encontrar o erro ?

Exemplo:

```
arr[0] = 23

coresLinhasPorPocsag[0] = "#4d79ff"
```

> **Resultado** = 23 na cor "#4d79ff"

```
 arr[1] = 0 

coresLinhasPorPocsag[1] = "#ff6600"
```

> **Resultado** = 0 na cor "#ff6600"

E assim por diante.

Segue código:

```
 "data": "somatoriaEcmUltimas24h",
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        let linha = ''
                        let coresLinhasPorPocsag = ["#4d79ff", "#ff6600", "#00cc88", "#b31aff"]
                    let arr = (data.split(','))
                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                          linha += "<div class='row' style='color:'" + coresLinhasPorPocsag[arr[i].indexOf(arr[i].length)] +  "'>" + arr[i] +  "</div>"
                    }
                return linha
            }
        },
```

Comment: Eu não conseguir compreender sua dúvida, se explicar melhor dou um jeito de te ajudar.

Comment: @Marconi Eu preciso associar o índice do array de cores com o índice do array da lista. Eu editei a pergunta com exemplo

Comment: ...`+ coresLinhasPorPocsag[i]`  ?

Comment: @bfavaretto já tentei, não deu certo... porque na arra[i] vai estar o numero da lista e não seu vetor ;s

Comment: Editei, não seria `+ coresLinhasPorPocsag[i]`?

Comment: @bfavaretto verdade, eu querendo fazer algum muito 'bonito' acabei fugindo do simples, apenas passar o contator... Deu certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi o que você quer, seria isso?

```js
function coresLinhasPorPocsag() {
  let linha = ''
  const coresLinhasPorPocsag = ["#4d79ff", "#ff6600", "#00cc88", "#b31aff"]
  const arr = [23,0,0]
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    linha += `<div class="row" style="color: ${coresLinhasPorPocsag[i]}">${arr[i]}</div>`
  }
  return linha
}

window.document.body.innerHTML = coresLinhasPorPocsag()
```

Answer (score 1):

O ES6 introduzui o "for-in". Ele permite percorrer os index's de um array.

```js
function exemplo() {
  let linha = '';
  const coresLinhasPorPocsag = ["#4d79ff", "#ff6600", "#00cc88", "#b31aff"];
  const arr = [23,0,0];
  for(let index in arr) {
    linha += `<div class="row" style="color: ${coresLinhasPorPocsag[index]}">${arr[index]}</div>`;
  }
  return linha;
}
```